# Accessing source code of PowerApps and hosting it elsewhere

Tags: azure, powerapps

We are looking into using PowerApps to develop apps quickly. However, we are concerned about dependency on Azure and inability to access the source code.

We are interested in understanding the transportability of an app in PowerApps.

**1)** Can we access the source code?

**2)** In a scenario where PowerApps does not satisfy our needs, can we take away the source code and manage everything ourselves?

**3)** Can we deploy the code in another cloud provider such as AWS or Google Cloud or our own server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot access the source code. The whole point of PowerApps is that it is a zero code environment. Therefore you cannot take the code and use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we access the source code for Power Apps?

Yes. You can use `export to zip`.

Inside the zip there's a `.msapp` file. You also unzip that.
There's a ton of `json` files. It includes your Power Apps code.

See also:

- running a diff on two Powerapps: https://github.com/microsoft/powerapps-tools#powerapps-review-tool
- A `Flow` / `Power Automate` that **exports** your code to **github**: https://github.com/SeaDude/seattlePowerAppers/blob/master/outlines/powerappsVersionControl.md